# Video Segmented Streaming Android

Tags: android, video

What I want to happen is like youtube wherein it shows video advertisement first and then plays the second video[the real video]. These videos are from web and I need to play them in my VideoView. Thanks to Lazy Ninja for his codes because I achieved what I want, but is it possible to use VideoView rather than SurfaceView? If yes, what are pros and cons of it? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setNextMediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29)() was added in API level 16 for that purpose.
If your target is above API 16, this should do the job.
If your target is below API 16, the following can work.
In one my projects, I did it just using MediaPlayer().
In that case, I set `setDataSource`() in `onCompletion(){};` without inializing the MediaPlayer again.

```
public class Player extends Activity implements
        OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private MediaPlayer player;
    private SurfaceView surface;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = surface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  
        playVideo(firstUrl);  
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        playVideo(nextClipUrl);
    }
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        holder.setFixedSize(player.getVideoWidth(), player.getVideoHeight());
        player.start();
    }

    private void playVideo(String url) {
        try {

            if (player == null) {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            }
            else {
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
            }
            player.setDataSource(url);
            player.setDisplay(holder);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepare();
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Exception Error", t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you but I am supporting API level 8 as the minSdkVersion. Is it still possible to achieve my goal?

Comment: Yeah! Like I have explained I did i in one of my project just using MediaPlayer(). Add the OnCompletionListener(), and change the source in onCompletion().

Comment: Hi @Lazy Ninja, I just want to use VideoView because it has automatic buttons play/pause. Is using VideoView than SurfaceView a bad practice that is why you are using SurfaceView?Thanks.

Comment: @kads Using VideoView is fine. It is more easier. Add onCompletionListener to the VideoView and change the source onCompletion().

Comment: Hi @Lazy Ninja. Video stutters while playing them in Android 4.4 and Gingerbread. But the video plays perfectly in Jelly Bean. What could be the problem? What I do is live streaming. I have m3u8 file here. Hope you could help me.